# Jcalender date format not matching MYSQL

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

I am making a Application Using Java. to pick the date i am using JCalender.jar file , and saving it in MYSQL . their date format does not match MYSQL date format . how can i change it

Comment: You shouldn't be sending the date to the database as a string in the first place. Use a prepared statement and `setDate`.

Comment: While running the insert into query from your java code use this function to convert string into date STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')    provide the code for further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this isn't really a Swing question but more of a JDBC question. As Jon Skeet already pointed out, you shouldn't be trying to embed a formatted date into a SQL statement. Instead, you should use PreparedStatement's [setDate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) method, passing in an instance of java.sql.Date. Using that method will insulate you from details like what date format the database expects (you won't know or care) which in turn means that your code won't break if it's run against a database expecting a different format from the one that would work for you today.